# cambiar css a elemento html dentro de un id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo dos elementos con la clase 'stopTimer' y 'start timer' que esta dentro de un tr con un id.
Tal que asi:

```
<tr id='1'>
    <span class='stopTimer' style="display: none;">
        fin
    </span>
    <span class='startTimer'>
        inicio
    </span>
</tr>
<tr id='2'>
    <span class='stopTimer' style="display: none;">
        fin
    </span>
    <span class='startTimer'>
        inicio
    </span>
</tr>
<tr id='3'>
    <span class='stopTimer' style="display: none;">
        fin
    </span>
    <span class='startTimer'>
        inicio
    </span>
</tr>
```

Pues cuando pulso start timer quiero quitar el display:none a stoptimer y ocultar el start.

El start (de todas las filas) lo he ocultado asi en el onclick:

```
$("#panelDoing").on("click", ".startTimer", function (event) {
    let tarea=$(this).patents("tr").attr("id");
    document.querySelectorAll('span.startTimer')
    .forEach((span)=>{
        if(this==span)return;

        span.style.display='none';
    });
});
```

Como podria hacer en esta misma función para mostrar SOLO el stop de esta fila?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás delegando correctamente el evento. Solo te hace falta buscar los respectivos elementos dentro de su contenedor.

`$(this).parent().find (".startTimer").toggle(); $(this).parent().find (".stopTimer").toggle();`

El método `toggle` muestra u oculta el elemento afectado según este sea visible u oculto.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la Opcion mas fácil es usar tus clases con Numerador Unico:
te dejo un ejemplo con tu codigo mas sencillo:

```js
function iniciar(id)
{
    $(".startTimer"+id).hide("slow");
  $(".stopTimer"+id).show("slow");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<tr>
    <span class='stopTimer1' style="display: none;">
        fin
    </span>
    <span class='startTimer1' onclick="iniciar(1)">
        inicio
    </span>
</tr>
<tr>
    <span class='stopTimer2' style="display: none;">
        fin
    </span>
    <span class='startTimer2' onclick="iniciar(2)">
        inicio
    </span>
</tr>
<tr>
    <span class='stopTimer3' style="display: none;">
        fin
    </span>
    <span class='startTimer3' onclick="iniciar(3)">
        inicio
    </span>
</tr>
```

Asi es mas sencillo en Vez de Colocar ID a los TR mejor coloca a los SPAN